# How do you reset the workflow status of a purchase requisition from completed to submitted programatically in X++?

Tags: workflow, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

MS Dynamics AX 2009:

I need to do this from the Purchase Order Screen, so I only have the Purchase Requisition number available from the PurchLines Table.

Your help would be really greatly appreciated as there is nothing yet on the net available (that I can find) and there are missing classes in the AX 2009 Tutorials.

All helpful answers will definitely get an upvote from me.

Edit: Purpose is to force the existing workflow to re-execute on the Purchase Requisition from "Submitted" stage when a button is clicked on the Purchase Order Screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer (code) to submit it to the workflow again:

workflowCorrelationId = Workflow::activateFromWorkflowTemplate(workflowTemplateName,recId,note,NoYes::No,'userid');

Answer (score 1):

This will reset the workflow state and status fields in PurchReqTable, but it won't execute any workflow logic:

```
PurchReqTable::setWorkflowState(PurchReqTable::find(PurchLine.PurchReqId).RecId, PurchReqWorkflowState::Submitted);
```

Comment: I would like to get the Workflow Status reset from complete to submitted so that the document can go through the existing workflow process again.