# Dynamics AX Workflows

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I have a quastion regarding AX workflows.

I remove an automated task from existing workflow. I saved and versionized corectlly without any erros and finally I activate the saved version with success.

I create some SalesOrders and triger the workflow , then  I can see under the "workflow History form" in "SalesOrders form" that these orders still follow the old workflow and not the new one.

What options I have in order my SalesOrders follow the newest (and already activated ) workflow

*CIL compile or AOS restart is not an option (Prod System)

Thanks,
Nikos

Comment: Is this really an X++ question, or a doubt at a more functional level?  Here is an [example to how to reset the workflow status of a purchase requisition via x++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/634478/how-do-you-reset-the-workflow-status-of-a-purchase-requisition-from-completed-to)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this specific problem that at least worked for me. 
I delete the individual bach jobs for worflow messaging.

Workflow due date processing,
Workflow line-item notifications,
Workflow message processing,

I open the workflow infostracture configurator....and recreate them.
Now my orders follow the correct workflow.